# How can I fix this wiki link parsing regular expression?

Tags: regex, sed, wiki

I've got an old wiki that I'm converting to a new wiki which uses Markdown and `[[]]` wiki link format. Unfortunately, the old wiki is *really* old and had *many* ways of producing links, incl. CamelCase, single-bracket (`[]`) wiki links, among others.

I'm converting w/regular expressions in `sed` and use the following regular expression to convert stand-alone CamelCase links to double-bracket (`[[]]`) wiki links:

```
s/([^[|])([A-Z][a-z]+[A-Z][A-Za-z]+)([^]|])/\1\[\[\2\]\]\3/g
```

Unfortunately, the one problem with the above (in my attempt to not convert CamelCase in existing single-bracket wiki links, since there's a mix of both) is that something like `[BluetoothConnection|UsingBluetoothIndex]` will get converted to `[BluetoothConnection|Using[[BluetoothInde]]x]`.

How can I resolve this issue and force the match to be more greedy and therefore fail and not make a substitution in that case? If `sed`'s enhanced regular expressions turn out to be too limiting, I'm willing to pass through `perl` instead of `sed`.

Comment: What is your expected output for string `[BluetoothConnection|UsingBluetoothIndex]`

Comment: `[BluetoothConnection|UsingBluetoothIndex]` should be left untouched for processing by later regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright can you try this:

```
$ echo "UsingBluetoothIndex" | sed -E 's!([^\[\|]?)([A-Z][a-z]+[A-Z][A-Za-z]+)($|\b|[]|])!\1\[\[\2\]\]\3!g'
Output: [[UsingBluetoothIndex]]

$ echo "[BluetoothConnection|UsingBluetoothIndex]" | sed -E 's!([^\[\|]?)([A-Z][a-z]+[A-Z][A-Za-z]+)($|\b|[]|])!\1\[\[\2\]\]\3!g'
Output: [[[BluetoothConnection]]|[[UsingBluetoothIndex]]]
```

**Update:**

Alright I believe now I have regex for your problem using [perl's negative look behind directive](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). So here it is:

```
perl -pe 's#(^|\b)((?![|\[])[A-Z][a-z]+[A-Z][A-Za-z]+(?![|\]]))($|\b)#\[\[\2\]\]#g'

echo "BluetoothConnection" | perl -pe 's#(^|\b)((?![|\[])[A-Z][a-z]+[A-Z][A-Za-z]+(?![|\]]))($|\b)#\[\[\2\]\]#g'
Output: [[BluetoothConnection]]

echo "[BluetoothConnection|UsingBluetoothIndex]" | perl -pe 's#(^|\b)((?![|\[])[A-Z][a-z]+[A-Z][A-Za-z]+(?![|\]]))($|\b)#\[\[\2\]\]#g'
Output: [BluetoothConnection|UsingBluetoothIndex]
```

All it is doing is checking if text is not starting with '|' or '[' and NOT ending with `|` or `]` then enclose it in `[[` and `]]`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `[BluetoothConnection|UsingBluetoothIndex]` should be left as-is, not converted to `[[[BluetoothConnection]]|[[UsingBluetoothIndex]]]`.

Comment: Oh, and one should not backslash-escape special characters within a character class in `sed`'s regular expressions as they're no longer considered special (except a leading '^', although ']' & '-' must be placed at specific positions to be understood). See `man re_format`. At least, this is the case under BSD/Mac OS X (which I'm running).

Comment: @morgant: I provided an alternative solution to your problem using perl, please see update section above.

Comment: Okay, thanks to the link you provided I now fully understand Perl's look-arounds. I also hadn't considered using `(^|\b)` & `($|\b)` to force it to full word boundaries! I'm now piping through the following and it works flawlessly: `perl -pe "s/(^|\b|_)((?<![\[|])[A-Z][a-z]+[A-Z][A-Za-z]+(?![\]|]))($|\b|_)/\1\[\[\2\]\]\3/g"`. (BTW, it looks like you were accidentally using a look-ahead instead of look-behind in your example.) Excellent solution & education on look-arounds!

Comment: @morgant: Thanks and I'm very glad that it is working for you now the way you wanted and yes you are right I used negative look-ahead :)