# Parsing wiki templates calls with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, wiki

All that I need is to split the wiki template call to parameter parts. In the very basic scenario it is just splitting by `|` so `{{template|unnamed_parameter|param1=value1}}` would be split to `{{template`, `unnamed_parameter`, `param1=value1` and `}}`.

But things are complicating when the pipe character is used for other purposes like for wikilinks `[[link|title]]` etc.

Any suggestions how to do this task in the easiest way? :)

**Update:** Sorry for possible misunderstanding but `{{template|unnamed_parameter|param1=value1}}` is just an example. For more information about wiki templates you can look at the following resource: [http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Templates](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aTemplates)

Answer (score 1):

Please look at this Q&A: [How can I fix this wiki link parsing regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442432/how-can-i-fix-this-wiki-link-parsing-regular-expression/5442759#5442759)

My answer (in Update section) there using `perl regex` is doing pretty much similar Wiki link parsing.

## Update:

Alright here is the perl regex for your case:

```
echo "{{template|unnamed_parameter|param1=value1}}" |  \
perl -pe 's#(^|\b)((?![|\[]){{(.+?)\|(.+?)\|(.+?)}}(?![|\]]))($|\b)#{{$3, $4, $5 and }}#g'

Output: {{template, unnamed_parameter, param1=value1 and }}
```

**Q:** are you sure you need `and` here before closing `}}` otherwise just edit above regex:

And now checking above solution against string `[[link|title]]`

```
echo "[[link|title]]" |  \
perl -pe 's#(^|\b)((?![|\[]){{(.+?)\|(.+?)\|(.+?)}}(?![|\]]))($|\b)#{{$3, $4, $5 and }}#g'

Output: [[link|title]] # remains unchanged as per your requirements
```

Comment: @DixonD: Would it be possible for you to extract various template calls from the page you've linked and list them in your original question here.

Answer (score -1):

regex that assumes your wiki template has always 3 parts:
*update to exclude false match to template `{{template|[[link|name]]}}`*

```
regex:       \{\{(.+?)\|[^\[]{2}(.+?)\|(.+?)[^\]]{2\}\}
replacment:  $1,$2,$3
input:       {{template|unnamed_parameter|param1=value1}}
output:      template,unnamed_parameter,param1=value1
```

it's a simple regex using reluctant quantifiers and escaping the "special" meaning of `{}|` using `\` 
by including `\{\{ \}\}` to the regex you avoid matches on `[[ ]]` pattern.

Comment: Your regex fails even for {{template|[[link|name]]}}

Comment: changing to `\{\{(.+?)\|[^\[]{2}(.+?)\|(.+?)[^\]]{2\}\}` will exclude the match for `{{template|[[link|name]]}}`